# ClickOnce falha ao carregar relatório Crystal Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wpf

Tenho uma aplicação WPF em C# e alguns relatórios dessa aplicação. Ao instalar a aplicação com o ClickOnce os relatórios não são chamados e aparece a mensagem de falha ao carregar relatório.

As DLLs funcionam quando executo minha aplicação pelo VS e se crio um instalador com outra solução (Inno Setup), funciona perfeitamente, mas com o ClickOnce não roda. As DLLs estão setadas como `true` em Copy Local e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se você setou o pacote do *Crystal Reports* como pré-requisito de publicação pelo *Visual Studio*.

Para fazer isso vá em **Properties** do seu projeto (botão direito) na aba **Publish** clique no botão **Prerequisites...**. Marque o pacote do *Crystal Reports* e defina as opções de download no mesmo local da sua aplicação.

Isso fará com que o instalador do *ClickOnce* verifique se o cliente possui ou não os componentes redistribuíveis e decida pela instalação dos mesmos juntamente com a instalação da sua aplicação.

### No caso de não encontrar os pacotes do Crystal Reports

- Baixe os arquivos *clickonce32/64* RTM nesse site
  http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824
- Extraia os arquivos do .zip e copie a pasta `CRforVS_clickonce_13_0` para dentro da pasta `{Program Files (x86)}\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v*.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\`

Com isso deve ser possível visualizar o pacote **SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework 4.0**

Comment: nas opções para escolher os pre requisitos não encontro  o do crystal reports. tem alguma forma de habilitá-lo?

Comment: vou complementar a resposta

Comment: A instalação do pre requisito funcionou mas permaneceu a mensagem de falha ao carregar relatório. Uma dúvida que ficou foi que em Applilcation Files não apareceram os arquivos do Crystal Reports que tem no Projeto. Então para solucionar preciso de adicionar os arquivos de CR que tem no Projeto para as opções de Application Files

Comment: Não encontrei uma forma de adicionar os arquivos do CR nas opções de Application Files. Teria alguma forma de acrescentar esses arquivos?